# Menu bar is not tidy

Tags: html, css

I want to make a menu bar. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#reportingmenunav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#reportingmenunav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#reportingmenunav li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
   border: 1px solid black;  
   width: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="reportingmenunav">
    <ul>
       <li>A1
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>
           </ul>        
      </li>
      <li>B1</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

From the above code, I get the below output: 
[image]

A2 and A3 border is thicker than A1 and B1.

How do I clear them in order to make them tidy (like A1 and B1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
#reportingmenunav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#reportingmenunav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#reportingmenunav .menu > li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
   border: 1px solid black;  
   width: 50px;
}

#reportingmenunav .sub-menu > li {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#reportingmenunav .menu > li:last-child {
    border-top: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="reportingmenunav">
    <ul class="menu">
       <li>A1
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>
           </ul>        
      </li>
      <li>B1</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55kq7zkd/

Notes: last-child is supported by IE9 (not IE8)

To support for IE8, you can use first-child instead of last-child as the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/55kq7zkd/1/

**CSS:**

```
#reportingmenunav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#reportingmenunav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#reportingmenunav .menu > li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   width: 50px;
}

#reportingmenunav .sub-menu > li {
    border-top:1px solid black;
}

#reportingmenunav .menu > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this you had an extr ul in the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#reportingmenunav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#reportingmenunav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 30px;
}

#reportingmenunav li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
border: 1px solid black;  
width: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="reportingmenunav">
<ul>
   <li>A1

            <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>

  </li>
  <li>B1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```